# PHP exec,system,shell_exec not working with wget on ubuntu machine

Tags: php, ubuntu

i have a simple script which im testing at the moment but it's not working.

I have this simple lines :

```
$url = "http://www.google.com";   
system("wget --page-requisites ".$url);
```

The issue is that it does nothing, my website is located at /var/www/html/server_a which is where im checking if it downloaded the required page  but seems like it's doing nothing.

Im using a VPS with Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Have you checked the permissions in the folder `/var/www/html/`?

Comment: Can you check your error log, or alternatively turn error reporting on and see if it shows any warnings or errors?

Comment: Cannot write to 'www.example.com/index.html' (No such file or directory).
Converted 0 files in 0 seconds.
--2018-09-03 11:21:16--  http://www.google.com/
Resolving www.google.com (www.google.com)... 108.177.122.106, 108.177.122.147, 108.177.122.104, ...
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|108.177.122.106|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
www.google.com: Permission deniedwww.google.com/index.html: No such file or directory

Cannot write to 'www.google.com/index.html' (No such file or directory).

Comment: is /var/www/html/server_a owned by www-data:www-data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is sudo, you need to add sudo before you run this command.

```
$url = "http://www.google.com";   
system("sudo wget --page-requisites ".$url);
```

Comment: That doesn't sound like a good idea. Why would wget require sudo? Why do you assume that his user account is capable of `sudo`ing? You'd have to additionally type a password in which `system()` isn't doing.

Comment: That's not going to work as your not sending the password.

Comment: Hmn.. the user doesn't have enough permission. i wonder what is the alternative.

Comment: `system("echo password | sudo -S wget --page-requisites ".$url);`

Comment: I already fixed this , there was no need for sudo as it would bring alot of security issues , so i simply added permissions to the folder of the website to which it could download the wget